# When passing in an object that is going to be modified to a method, is there a way to indicate this?

Tags: c#

I have an object and it is passed to a method to be altered. This sort of behaviour seems quite rare so I want to make sure that other developers don't trip up on it and it's easy to see. Is there anything I can do to make it obvious what's happening?

The method adjusts some properties on the object, but it doesn't return the object. Perhaps it should return it?

`myObject = Processor(myObject);` would be redundant, but it would make it clearer...?

The only thing I can think of is adding `ref` before it in the interface but not sure if that's a good idea or not. Any ideas?

Comment: name your function well and comment it using ///.

Comment: why wouldn't the method names be clear?

Comment: I think myObject = Processor(myObject) would make it quite clear. You could also add a comment explaining your logic, of course.

Comment: I would use a void method that has a name that implies some operation on the object. For instance `sort(someList)` does not cause confusion, right?

Comment: A clear name implying that changes occur and a `void` return type should make it clear where those changes are happening.

Comment: "This sort of behaviour seems quite rare", in all honesty, it is not :)

Comment: Well if you change properties of the object, you keep the reference intact. So in a way, by pretending that a new object might be returned, you're actually deemphasizing the very point you're trying to make.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, returning the same reference doesn't make it clearer - in some cases such a method would be expected to clone the object and return a different version, e.g.

```
string Escape(string input)
```

Indeed, because a `void` method *can't* return anything, its very existence pretty much guarantees there will be side-effects. It doesn't state whether the side-effects will be on the target of the call or on a reference, but at least it implicitly highlights that you should think what the side-effects will be. A method returning a value could very easily be side-effect free.

Likewise using `ref` is just wrong - that suggests you want to be able to change the caller's variable to refer to a different object, which is in no way the same thing as modifying the data within an *existing* object. It gives the wrong impression.

Ultimately, there are two approaches to this:

- Don't have mutable types in the first place :)
- Rely on method naming and documentation

Comment: Thanks. I'll call the method something like PopulateProperties and have it return void so as to be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Returning the object would have no immediate added value in this case, because it would mean you would have to make a clone and return it, causing unneeded work and maybe causing performance issues.

In this case I would simply name your operation with a **verb**, that clearly indicates what it does, for example:

```
 void FillInMissingProperties(MyObject myObject);
```

Add some XML documentation with a short explanation.

Optionally extension methods can also be used to extend a class with this kind of methods:

```
myObject.FillInMissingProperties();
```